# some list append code in MIT App Inventor

Tags: listview, app-inventor

can someone please help me with this?
[image]

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The `append to list` block appends 2 lists, see also the [documentation](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/lists.html#append)

> Adds the items in the second list to the end of the first list.

There is no need to use a `for each item in list` block to do that...

---

You might be interested in learning how to work with lists:

[How to work with Lists](http://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/list-blocks-on-app-inventor/) by Saj

[How to work with Lists and Lists of lists](http://www.appinventor.org/bookChapters/chapter19.pdf) (pdf) by [appinventor.org](http://www.appinventor.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[From the above Image I recommend the Following blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGnhg.png)

It will loop through the new List after following appending the earlier Lists